# Using AVL Trees to solve Pancake Stack problem (not pancake sort)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm having quite some trouble with this problem on hand, here is a summary of what the problem is:

- A person creates pancakes of different weights.
- After creating a pancake, it will be inserted into a stack of pancakes in descending order of weights from bottom to top.
- All pancakes have weight > 0 and are unique.

The person wants to lift a stack of pancakes with a minimal weight of `w` grams. A requirement is that he must lift as few pancakes as possible.

Example: 5 pancakes created in order: 11g, 15g, 19g, 1g, 3g. They will be stacked from heaviest to lightest from bottom to top. If the person wants to lift at least 5g, he has to lift the stack of 11g, 3g and 1g pancakes as it is the minimal stack of pancakes that sum up to >5g.

The function I have to come up with, `minimumWeight(int n)` returns the weight of the pancake in the stack such that all of the pancakes above and including itself will have a weight at least `n` grams with the minimum number of pancakes. Any error handling is trivial and can be easily done. Hence for the above example, `minimumWeight(5)` will return 11.

I am not looking for codes but rather the idea to approach this using AVL Trees.

The skeleton code I was given is a self-balancing BST, and additionally, each node stores the sum of all the nodes in its subtree including itself. I am not forced to use the BST, but as the test cases goes up to huge numbers, an O(n) solution using array is not going to work.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I don't get your question exactly...Will list of pancakes always starts at top of stack? for example answer for 5g is {1g,3g,11g} not {11g}, isn't it?

Comment: the function only returns the bottom most pancake of the substack, such that the sum of weights of that pancake and all pancakes above it is more than or equal to a certain weight. Thus answer for 5g returns 11 instead of {11,3,1}.

Comment: A tree will work, but storing the sum of the weights would be quite slow as you would have to recalculate the sum for every node on each insertion.Why not simply use the tree of weights and then do an in-order traversal summing the weights as you go and return the weight of the node when your search weight is exceeded?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's a constraint given by the problem set as I am not allowed to edit the class attributes. I was thinking of an in-order traversal, but storing the sum of the weights will mean that the code will not work if I have to traverse beyond the root of the tree to the right.